# Unexpected underline css artifact in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Once the first drop-down in this navigation menu gets clicked, it will be underlined as expected, once the menu loses focus (i.e. clicking somewhere else on the page), the underline at the end of the tag is not removed.

**It's happening in only in Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.85 m)**

I expect the the underline at the end to be completely removed.

Possible cause is that font-awesome is causing some issues with chrome.

image for clarification:

[image: underline incorrect]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11912/)

```js
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: dropdown.js v3.3.5
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+ function($) {
  'use strict';

  // DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var backdrop = '.dropdown-backdrop'
  var toggle = '[data-toggle="dropdown"]'
  var Dropdown = function(element) {
    $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
  }

  Dropdown.VERSION = '3.3.5'

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector)

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
  }

  function clearMenus(e) {
    if (e && e.which === 3) return
    $(backdrop).remove()
    $(toggle).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      var $parent = getParent($this)
      var relatedTarget = {
        relatedTarget: this
      }

      if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return

      if (e && e.type == 'click' && /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName) && $.contains($parent[0], e.target)) return

      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger($.Event('hidden.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))
    })
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function(e) {
    var $this = $(this)

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    clearMenus()

    if (!isActive) {
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
        // if mobile we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
        $(document.createElement('div'))
          .addClass('dropdown-backdrop')
          .insertAfter($(this))
          .on('click', clearMenus)
      }

      var relatedTarget = {
        relatedTarget: this
      }
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $this
        .trigger('focus')
        .attr('aria-expanded', 'true')

      $parent
        .toggleClass('open')
        .trigger($.Event('shown.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))
    }

    return false
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function(e) {
    if (!/(38|40|27|32)/.test(e.which) || /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return

    var $this = $(this)

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    if (!isActive && e.which != 27 || isActive && e.which == 27) {
      if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).trigger('focus')
      return $this.trigger('click')
    }

    var desc = ' li:not(.disabled):visible a'
    var $items = $parent.find('.dropdown-menu' + desc)

    if (!$items.length) return

    var index = $items.index(e.target)

    if (e.which == 38 && index > 0) index-- // up
      if (e.which == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++ // down
        if (!~index) index = 0

    $items.eq(index).trigger('focus')
  }


  // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown = Plugin
  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


  // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function() {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
  // ===================================

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
    })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-menu', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(jQuery);
```

```css
/*css */

.navigation ul {
  margin: 9px;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation ul li {
  padding: 0 16px;
  display: inline;
}
.navigation ul ul li a {
  padding: 8px;
}
.navigation ul ul li {
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation ul li a i {
  display: inline
}
/*bootstrap stuff*/

a:hover {
  color: #2a6496;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/*font-awesome*/

@font-face{

font-family:FontAwesome;
 src:url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0) format('eot'),
url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0) format('woff'),
url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0) format('truetype'),
url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
 font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;

}
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.fa-angle-down:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
.fa-home:before {
  content: "\f015";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                with whitespace 
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
             </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a>
                       has artifact
                  </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                without whitespace <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a>
                      does not have artifact
                  </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                with whitespace 
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                and some text    
             </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a>
                       it seems it only happens when ending on a font-awsome icon.
                  </a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
                last item               
             </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How would i go about and fix this?
preferably using css, leaving the html intact. Both the text and the arrow should be underlined

-edit:
some Answers/comments point out that removing the white-space will fix this issue.
I would also like to understand why the white-space is still underlined after losing hover/focus.

Comment: I know it'll sound stupid, but there's *space* between your `<i>` and `</a>` closing tag, remove this and you're good to go.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay yes this will indeed remove the underline, although I don't understand why the underline isn't removed once the element loses hover/focus

Comment: @Lars, your css has `underline` applied both on `hover` and `focus` state. If you will check carefully, the underline properly show and remove when you just `hover` on the link. But once you click the link to open the dropdown, here now applies the `focus` css too and at this moment both the `hover` and `focus` css arr applied on link item. When you take away your mouse either on dropdown items or to any white space area. The `hover` css removes and so the underline, but it is the `focus` css which still sticks there and shows the underline.

Comment: @RaviKhandelwal I've removed the focus css completely (see edit), yet once the item is clicked, the white-space will be underlined. I'm unable to  recreate the the faulty scenario using chrome's inspector. Toggling focus/hover on `.dropdown`, `.dropdown-toggle` and the `<i>`-tag does not underline the white-space.

Comment: This was resolved by the Chrome developers. Artefact should be correctly removed after losing focus.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary 'whitespace' just before the closing `</a>` tag -

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>            </a>
```

Change above like this -

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Write below code out of the anchor tag (`<a></a>`)

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have pointed out that i would like the arrow to be underlined on hover/focus.